# Segunda Chance ... python Becrowd

Tags: python-3.x

Em uma faculdade de um mundo muito distante, dois jovens professores buscam ajudar seus alunos a estudarem e melhorarem seus conhecimentos sobre a disciplina de programação, fazendo com que notas mais altas sejam conquistadas. Para isso, desenvolveram a estratégia da "Segunda Chance". A "Segunda Chance" consiste em uma nova atividade com os mesmos problemas da atividade original, porém com um prazo estendido e com a disponibilização de vídeos detalhados com a resolução de cada problema, de modo a incentivar que os alunos revisitem e comparem suas próprias propostas de solução.

Para aumentar ainda mais o incentivo para a turma, os professores concedem um bônus de dois pontos sobre a nota original para aqueles que resolverem TODOS os problemas dentro do prazo estendido, isto é, que obtiverem dez na nova atividade, o que é uma "moleza", considerando que basta assistir as resoluções e aplicá-las. Mas é claro, o bônus é concedido até o limite de dez pontos, ou seja, caso a soma do bônus com a nota original resulte em um valor superior a dez, a nota final será dez.

Como esperado, os alunos ficaram contentes e empolgados com a oportunidade. De tão agradecidos, ofereceram um software aos dois professores, de modo a reduzir um pouco da carga extra de trabalho que eles terão para recalcular as notas.

Você se voluntariou para implementar esse software, que precisa receber um valor inicial indicando a quantidade de alunos da turma, seguido pelas notas originais de cada aluno e pelas notas obtidas na nova atividade. O programa deverá exibir a quantidade de alunos que tiveram suas notas alteradas, assim como as notas originais e finais de cada aluno, destacando aqueles que aumentaram as notas.

Entrada

Na primeira linha haverá um número natural N (1 <= N <= 999) indicando a quantidade de alunos da turma;

Nas próximas N linhas, haverá a nota original de cada aluno, que são valores reais no intervalo fechado [ 0,10 ];

Por fim, nas N linhas seguintes, haverá a nota obtida na nova atividade por cada aluno, também situadas no intervalo fechado [ 0,10 ].

Note que as N primeiras notas correspondem as notas originais dos N primeiros alunos, e as próximas N notas correspondem as notas da "Segunda Chance" dos mesmos alunos. Portanto, se N = 5, a 1ª nota é do primeiro aluno e a 6ª nota também é do primeiro aluno (original e "Segunda Chance), a 2ª nota é do segundo aluno e a 7ª também, a 5ª é do quinto aluno e a 10ª também.

Saída

A primeira linha será a frase 'NOTAS ALTERADAS: ', sem apóstrofos e completamente em maiúsculo, em que deve ser substituído pela quantidade de alunos que tiveram suas notas originais alteradas em decorrência da aplicação do bônus;

As próximas N linhas serão as notas de todos os alunos, na mesma ordem dada na entrada, iniciando com asterisco ('*') para indicar as notas que foram alteradas e hífen ('-') para indicar aquelas que não foram, seguido pela posição da referida nota entre parênteses. O formato de cada linha pode ser observada nos exemplos, onde se destacam três características: (I) a posição tem sempre três dígitos, completada com zeros à esquerda quando necessário; (II) todas as notas são exibidas com duas casas decimais e; (III) todas as notas ocupam cinco colunas, incluindo o caractere ponto, e completadas com zeros à esquerda quando necessário.

Samples Input Samples Output (Entrada)

5

10.00

10.00

10.00

10.00

10.00

0.00

0.00

0.00

0.00

0.00

Samples Input Samples Output(saida)

NOTAS ALTERADAS: 0

-(001) original: 10.00 | final: 10.00

-(002) original: 10.00 | final: 10.00

-(003) original: 10.00 | final: 10.00

-(004) original: 10.00 | final: 10.00

-(005) original: 10.00 | final: 10.00

Samples Input Samples Output (Entrada)

5

7.00

6.00

10.00

1.00

9.00

10.00

10.00

10.00

10.00

10.00

Samples Input Samples Output(saida)

NOTAS ALTERADAS: 4

*(001) original: 07.00 | final: 09.00

*(002) original: 06.00 | final: 08.00

-(003) original: 10.00 | final: 10.00

*(004) original: 01.00 | final: 03.00

*(005) original: 09.00 | final: 10.00

Samples Input Samples Output (Entrada)

5

7.00

6.00

10.00

1.00

9.00

8.00

9.00

7.00

5.00

10.00

Samples Input Samples Output(saida)

NOTAS ALTERADAS: 1

-(001) original: 07.00 | final: 07.00

-(002) original: 06.00 | final: 06.00

-(003) original: 10.00 | final: 10.00

-(004) original: 01.00 | final: 01.00

*(005) original: 09.00 | final: 10.00

Samples Input Samples Output (Entrada)

3

10.00

10.00

10.00

10.00

10.00

10.00

Samples Input Samples Output(saida)

NOTAS ALTERADAS: 0

-(001) original: 10.00 | final: 10.00

-(002) original: 10.00 | final: 10.00

-(003) original: 10.00 | final: 10.00

Samples Input Samples Output (Entrada)

1

0.00

9.00

Samples Input Samples Output(saida)

NOTAS ALTERADAS: 0

-(001) original: 00.00 | final: 00.00

***Bem Vim tentando um atv do Becrowd mas mesmo dando o valor correto mas f da como resultado 'Runtime Error' gostaria de saber onde estou errando***

```
contadorP = 0
contadorS = 0
qntdAlunos = []

numeroAluno = int(input())
qntdAlunos.append(numeroAluno)

n = 0
for i in range(0,qntdAlunos[n]):
     if qntdAlunos[n] != 0:
          vetNotaOrig = []
          while qntdAlunos[n] != contadorP:
               notaAlunoOriginal = int(input())
               vetNotaOrig.append(notaAlunoOriginal)
               contadorP += 1

          vetNotaAtv = []
          while qntdAlunos[n] != contadorS:
               notaAlunoAtv = int(input())
               vetNotaAtv.append(notaAlunoAtv)
               contadorS += 1

          while True:
               y = 0
               vetFinal = []
               while qntdAlunos[n] != y:
                    vetFinal = vetNotaAtv
                    vetFinal[y] = vetNotaOrig[y] + 2
                    if vetFinal[y] >= 10:
                         vetFinal[y] = 10
                    y += 1       

        
               p = 0
               nA = 0
               while qntdAlunos[n] != p:
                    if vetNotaOrig[p] != vetFinal[p]:
                         nA += 1
                         p += 1
                    else:
                         nA += 0
                         p += 1
        
               y = 0
               z = 1
               print('NOTAS ALTERADAS:',nA)
               while qntdAlunos[n] != y:
                    if vetNotaOrig[y] != vetFinal[y]:
                         x = '*'
                    else:
                         x = '-'
               print(x,'({:03d})'.format(z),'original:',f'{vetNotaOrig[y]:0>5.2f}','|','final:',f'{vetFinal[y]:0>5.2f}')
               
               z += 1
               y += 1
            
          break      
     else:
          n += 1
```

Comment: Deixei umas orientações no campo de comentários [da primeira vez que fez a pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/555068/70). Você pode editar a postagem original que automaticamente ela entrará numa reavaliação, e se atender ao objetivo do site, pode ser reaberta.